# Add further information to Rails Select list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, select, associations

I have a select list drop down in my Rails application, in the form for creating a new record.

```
<li>Surveyor Name<span><%= f.select :surveyorperson_id, Person.all.collect { |x| [x.personname, x.id]}, {:selected => (@kase.surveyorperson_id rescue "")} %></span></li>
```

This is so the user can choose from a list of Surveyor's names which one they want to associate with the Case they are creating.

What I would like to do is have the company name of the Surveyor listed next to their name in brackets.

At the moment the code looks like this:

```
<li>Appointed Company<span><%= f.select :appointedsurveyor_id, Company.all.collect {|m| [m.companyname, m.id]}, {:selected => (@kase.appointedsurveyor_id rescue "")} %></span></li>
<li>Appointed Surveyor<span><%= f.select :surveyorperson_id, Person.all.collect { |x| [x.personname, x.id]}, {:selected => (@kase.surveyorperson_id rescue "")} %></span></li>
```

Is it possible to have the company that a surveyor works for outputting after their name?

The associations are as follows:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kases
  has_many :people

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :kases # foreign key in join table
  belongs_to :company
```

I have also changed to output of the company records to their names rather than their ID numbers'.

```
def to_s; companyname; end
```

Thanks in advance!

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to your Person model that returns a string containing the persons name and the Company he/she is working for:

```
def name_and_company
  return "#{name} [#{company.name}]"
end
```

If you do not want to have this in your model (because this is view related code), you can, instead of just calling

```
x.personname
```

inside the `Person.all.collect` call, you can use something like

```
"#{name} [#{company.name}]"
```

Comment: Once I have added the def name_and_company, how do I call that method from within the select code in the view?

Comment: instead of calling x.personname, you call x.name_and_company